# Incorrect phone number format when dialing from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization, cellular-carriers

- iPhoneXs
- iOS 13.4 (also affected 13.3.x)
- Carrier: AT&T
- e-SIM (no physical SIM)

On a recent trip out of the U.S. I added a 2nd SIM card and a local calling plan (Turkcell) so I could use my phone without incurring roaming charges. All was fine.

**PROBLEM:** When I returned, I deactivated that plan, and removed the SIM card from the phone. However, the iPhone retained the incorrect phone number formatting on the dialpad screen. See screenshot below for example:

[image: dialpad]

This might seem like a frivolous detail, but it actually slows me down when dialing numbers "manually" since it always looks like I've entered the number incorrectly, skipped a digit or added an extra one, etc. I just want to get it back to the correct format.

Once I hit the green Dial button, the number is correctly formatted, so it's just doing this on the pre-dial screen. See below:

[image: dialing]

**Thing's I've tried:**

- Soft resetting the phone (Vol+, Vol-, then press+hold Power until it reboots)
- Changing Language under Settings > Language & Region e.g. from English U.S. to something else and then back again
- Adding / removing additional keyboards
- Turning Roaming on/off
- Turning Cellular Data on/off
- Disabling the cellular line under Settings > Cellular and then re-enabling it
- Calling AT&T and having them "re-provision" my phone
- Updating from iOS 13.3 to 13.4

**Things I have NOT tried:**

- Going to an Apple Store (they're closed here right now due to COVID-19)
- Doing a full Backup / Restore of the phone
- The various "Resets" under Settings > Reset (was afraid to lose my stored passwords/WiFi settings but if anyone thinks that would fix it, I will try...)

Anyone ever see this or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the extact same issue. I believe this is an issue with the eSim. I had to put a US SIM in and it corrected the issue with the phone numbers displaying wrong when dialing manually.

Comment: I was going to actually post an update - I had previously used a Turkish SIM card while traveling and I guess there was a bug in an earlier iOS (12 or 13, can't remember which version) where even after switching back to US/AT&T it retained the foreign dial pattern - even after the SIM was removed/deactivated. A couple of weeks ago I switched from AT&T to Google Fi (eSIM) and during that activation process, the dial pattern problem finally resolved itself. Not really a good solution, since without a 2nd US-based SIM or eSIM to activate, there is really no way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old topic.  I just have the same issue and found a solution.  it worked for me, you might want to try.

- Disable the cellular line under Settings
- Restart iPhone
- Enable the cellular line under Settings

good luck,

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue. I tried all the things the original poster did above too. I even tried Apple support to no avail. After reading a similar article (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251341824), I think the common thread is the eSIM.

I called T-Mobile and after troubleshooting and trying a few other options, I had them delete/reissue my eSIM. It took a while for them to do this, but it resolved the issue! Hopefully this will help someone else.